# select radio value from popup modal without reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a modal popup. If any clicks on that modal then a popup window opens and radio button appears. If click on any radio button and submit that popup then selected radio value should be show in paragraph tag without reloading page.

I have code but it is not working.

**My modal button is: (index.php)**

```
<div id="dvPassport1">
            <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Select Loyalty Membership</label><br>
        <a class="showModal btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-queryid="q11" > View Loyalty Membership</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Employee IDs</label>
        <p></p>
        </div>
         </div>
```

**Now If clicks on View Loyalty Membership button** then a popup opens (code is below)(index.php):

```
<!-- popup modal-->
<div id="id01" class="modal">

 <form class="modal-content animate" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<div class="imgcontainer">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>

</div>

<div class="container">
     <div class="modalContent"></div>

</div>
</form>
</div>
<script>
// Get the modal1
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var modal = $("#id01");
$("a.showModal").on("click", function(){
    modal.fadeIn();
    var id = $(this).attr("data-queryid");
    var modalServiceUrl = "showstate.php?queryid7="+id;
    modal.find(".modalContent").load(modalServiceUrl);
});
});
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal1, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {

if (event.target == modal1) {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
<!-- end popup modal -->
```

**script is**(index.php)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btnGetValue').click(function() {
    var selValue = $('input[name=rbnNumber]:checked').val(); 
    $('p').html('<br/>Selected Radio Button Value is : <b>' + selValue + '</b>');
});
});

</script>
```

Above all code is in index.php

**showstate.php is:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['queryid7'])){

$queryid7 = $_GET['queryid7'];
echo"<div align='center' style='height:660px; overflow:auto;'  class='w3l-table-info'><h2>Select your Loyalty membership</h2><table id='table'><thead>
    <tr><th>&nbsp;</th>";
 $query12=mysql_query("select * from loyalty_group ORDER BY id") or die (mysql_error());
while($row12=mysql_fetch_array($query12))
        {
            $group_name1=$row12['group_name'];
            $id11=$row12['id'];
echo"<th><input type='radio' id='rbnNumber' name='rbnNumber' value='$id11'/>".$group_name1.'</th>';

        }
echo"<th>&nbsp;</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
echo"</tbody>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><br><button type='submit' id='btnGetValue' class='btn btn-primary'>Select</button></td></tr>

 </table></div>";
 ?>
```

Now if any any radio button selects the click on Select button then value of value='$id11' should show in **paragraph tag(p)**(index.php) **without reloading page(index.php)** and popup should be close.

Comment: In the <a> tag: <a class="showModal btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-queryid="q11" > View Loyalty Membership</a> Add href="#" it should prevent the page load when clicking it

Comment: Also if you don't want it to mess with the url you can use: href="javascript:void(0);"

Comment: thank you for reply. I tried, but it is reloading.

Comment: After adding href="javascript:void(0);" submit button from popup window not working.

Comment: The modal form does not have action specified. Add there the url you wish to post the data to.

Comment: Also if you want the submit button to save the radio value, you need to register the click event for it AFTER you have fetched the submit button from server(showstate.php)

Comment: can we connect team-viewer please? I trying it from 1 day.

Comment: Wait I'm trying to figure out how to do this in your case, the code you have is really close, just the $('#btnGetValue').click(function() {
    var selValue = $('input[name=rbnNumber]:checked').val(); 
    $('p').html('<br/>Selected Radio Button Value is : <b>' + selValue + '</b>');
});
}); part needs to run after you get the submit button

Comment: You need to take that part from index.php and add it to the end of your showstate.php

Comment: it should after php code or within php code?

Comment: Just like you have it in index.php just copy it from there to end of showstate.php AFTER php (include the <script> tags and document.ready)

Comment: I tried it but it reloads.

Comment: Make the submit button like this: <button type="button"...> <button type="submit" will try to send the form synchronously and reload the page. <button type="button" acts like a button not a form submit

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is working. But popup window also should be close. Please help.

Comment: Just add modal close code to the #btnGetValue).click function i.e.: modal1.style.display = "none";

Comment: paste modal1.style.display = "none"; after $('#btnGetValue').click(function() {    But it is not working

Comment: $("#id01").hide(); try this then. If you put it on the click event everytime you press submit it closes it automaticly, you might want to add this to the window.click event too to make it universal when you click outside the modal

Comment: Thank you very much..it is working.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help

Comment: hello sir/mam ...r u there?

Comment: Yes I have this site open at all times

Comment: If I want show value into text input(not within paragraph), then what should I do? means <p></p> replace <input type="text" id="id1" name="id1" value="" />. So that  can I post it in table.

Comment: $("#id1").val($('input[name=rbnNumber]:checked').val());

Comment: Thank you reply...I solved it by replacing $('#id1').html($('input:text').val(selValue));

Comment: Your code will set all inputs of type text on the document to the value of the radio so it's not recommended

Comment: Yes you are right. Your code will work for me. Thank you.

Comment: One more thing please..

Comment: If you need more help, we should use some real-time chat

Comment: How we can chat?

Comment: we can use skype, team-viewer etc.

Comment: do you have discord

Comment: No but i can download.

Comment: discord tag is #9538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<button type="submit"></button>` sends the form and reloads current page, because `<form action=..` is not specified. What you want to use here is `<button type="button"></button>`